# Laptop won't boot

Tags: boot

Out of the blue, my Dell Inspiron laptop has stopped booting.

- If I try to start it normally, it stops after a short while with "initramfs" as command prompt.
- If I try to start it in recovery mode, it reports a failure while checking the root file system, and then I get the command prompt with "initramfs".
- If I try to boot it from a USB-stick with ubuntu on it, it fails and I get "grub" as command prompt. The USB-stick works fine on another laptop.

I am not a computer specialist. I am willing to learn, and I have tried to find information on various forums, but I have discovered I was really out of my depth.
Could someone help me or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://medium.com/@aterro51/linux-how-to-fix-linux-mint-initramfs-prompt-at-boot-a6bced4fe49f).

Comment: The following link may help you find the problem, [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/).

Answer (score 2):

The solution was provided by Paul Benson in the comments. Thank you very much, Paul! (And thanks to sudodus for pointing to a useful thread to deal with the bootable USB-stick problem). I'm writing out the solution here to make it clear that the problem is solved as far as I am concerned.

The procedure is documented at the following link: https://medium.com/@aterro51/linux-how-to-fix-linux-mint-initramfs-prompt-at-boot-a6bced4fe49f. The error messages I received indicated that there was a problem with the root file system which prevented the computer from booting.

At the initramfs prompt, I first had to type the following:

(initramfs) **exit**

This command was useful to get the path of the root file system, which was displayed in one of the output lines:

> The root filesystem on [*path*] requires a manual fsck

The next command fixed the problem with the root file system:

(initramfs) **fsck** [*path*] **-y**

After that, I only needed to reboot.

(initramfs) **reboot**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)